# qt QNetworkReply download Media Stream from internet radio

Tags: qt, qt5, qtnetwork

i try write media stream to buffer and then to file

```
   buf.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
   file.setFileName("out.mp3");
   file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QFile::Truncate);
   mp3file.setDevice(&file);
```

attempts:

```
1.
void MainWindow::reply_readyRead()
{
    QByteArray qa;
    qa = reply->read(16 * 1024);
    buf.write(qa.data(),qa.size());
}

2.
    void MainWindow::reply_readyRead()
    {
    QByteArray qa;
    qa = reply->read(16 * 1024);
    buf.write(qa.data(),qa.size());
    mp3file.writeRawData(qa.data() ,qa.size());
    }
```

always out-file/buffer is broken(missed parts). you can listen this file here [MP3 FILE](http://rgho.st/8cKFyjGd4)

writing mp3 from static files(from url) goes well!

Answer (score 0):

You don't read all the data that is available. Either read all the data at once:

```
QByteArray qa = reply->readAll();
```

or try doing it in a loop:

```
QByteArray qa;
while (reply->bytesAvailable() > 0)
    qa += reply->read(16 * 1024);
```